# when to resize an image?

Tags: c#, image, image-processing

I am building a online store for hand made jewelry. Of course there is a lot of high quality pictures that i need to show, first in small sizes and when a client clicks on the image, than redirect him to a page with a same image in high quality.

What is a better way:

1. on saving image save two images one in low quality and the second in original quality 
   or
2. onload image use Bitmap to lower the quality?

Comment: Save them in different sizes. The positive about this is: higher quality, performance improvement.
The negative is, that if you want to change this picture size, you would have to resize them all again. (Which isn't a big trouble with a batch converter like irfanview).

Comment: got to agree with @Yami here, any potential benefit you would gain e.g. manageability/SEO/whatever would be greatly outweighed by the latency overhead of transmitting the higher resolution images

Comment: I agere with @Yami. For very high resolution images IIPImage http://iipimage.sourceforge.net/demo/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends. 
Resizing on demand causes a heavier server load. When a lot of people are accessing the site this might be an issue.

Resizing on upload reduces this problem.

Resizing on your client using image processing software does usually produce the best quality with low file size.

The "normal" resize-functions in .NET is far away from that quality.

Also: Consider caching. The IIS offers everything to use this, perhaps in combination with an eTag.

Answer (score 1):

I would resize them on upload/addition. I would also make sure to name them appropriately to their size, like `gold_ring_640_480.jpg`.

Then, should I need to change the size of the preview, I would add functionality to resize it lazily on demand if a required picture size does not exist.

```
Image_240p exists?
  not: create
       save _240p
use the image
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to save all image size . For my all website, I get image on the fly depend on dimension that I need. When have a request with file size, I will create a resized image on disk. In the next time, with the same request, I just check:

- if file already in browse cached, I will return the header mention that website just get image from cache.
- if file not in browse cache, I will check that "the file already generate in disk". If the file is available, just return the file to response
- if file not in browse cache and not in disk. I will generate it and return the file content.

For image caching you can see this reference :https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/caching

For image resize on the fly by .net: you can refer to : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/191424/Resizing-an-Image-On-The-Fly-using-NET